# Conflicting types with char*

Tags: c, pointers, function

I have a small program to test passing char* pointers in and out of functions.
When I compile with cc, I get warning and errors saying I have conflicting types even though all my variables are char* . Please enlighten

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    char* p = NULL;

    foo1(p);
    foo2();
}

void foo1(char* p1)
{
}

char* foo2(void)
{
    char* p2 = NULL;

    return p2;
}

p.c:11: warning: conflicting types for ‘foo1’
p.c:7: warning: previous implicit declaration of ‘foo1’ was here
p.c:15: error: conflicting types for ‘foo2’
p.c:8: error: previous implicit declaration of ‘foo2’ was here
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to prototype your functions before the main() function.

example:

```
void foo1(char *p1);
char* foo2(void);

int main(.......
```

Or just put the bodies for those functions above the main function.

Comment: Thanks, same problem! This error message also did not obviously point me to the problem either.

Answer (score 4):

As ghills said, to fix the error, move the function definitions above `main()` or put function prototypes there.

The reason for the error is that when the compiler sees:

```
foo1(p);
foo2();
```

before it sees either a declaration or definition of `foo1()` and `foo2()`, it assumes the return type of those functions is `int`.  In the early days of C, `int` was considered to be a reasonable default return type (there was no `void` type in the earliest versions of C).  Nowadays, omitting the return type is considered bad practice and compilers complain about it.

Comment: Not just the return type, but the type of the arguments are assumed to be int as well.  This causes problems when (for example) passing pointers to un-prototyped functions, when sizeof(void *) != sizeof(int)...

Comment: @ephemient, the type of the arguments are not assumed to be anything in particular. if there is no declaration, the function is implicitly declared as "extern int name();" (with C89). And more importantly, in C99 it's an error to omit a function declaration or to omit the return type. Arguments are promoted (char->int,float->double,...) and if the promoted types do not match the actual parameter types, then behavior is undefined.

Comment: @litb: I do remember that (at the very least) passing pointers to unprototyped variadic functions had significant issues in practice.  I don't recall the particulars of what ANSI C/C89/C99 specify are, so I'll defer to you on that.

Comment: @ephemient, since the function will be declared as "extern int name();", if the function is actually variadic, like "extern int name(int a, ...);" then undefined behavior will happen. For example, printf will always have to have a prototype declared prior to its call. But calling non-variadic functions without prototype is fine as long as the arguments have the right type in C89 (although this is deprecated).

Comment: Another problem is passing pointers to a function having a parameter with type void* but no prototype. You have to convert explicitly to void*, since the compiler can't do that for you since it doesn't know the types the arguments should have.